# the ajax code didn't work on a django app

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

I am working on a machine learning app with Django  and I have to pass the data  that I wont to use in the model to a views function using ajax and Jquery but the function didn't get called at all so whenever I submit the form is show nothing  I've try many solution but didn't work

### ps: I am still a beginner in JS

- 

here is the views function:

```
def Iris_classify(request):
    print('called1')
    if request.POST.get('action') =='post':
        print('caled2')
        sepal_length = float(request.POST.get('sepal_lenght'))
        sepal_width = float(request.POST.get('sepal_width'))
        petal_length = float(request.POST.get('petal_lenght'))
        petal_width = float(request.POST.get('petal_width'))
        model = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\Users\zakaria\Django\DataProject\Data_science\machinlearning\classifier_model.pickl")
        prediction_features=[sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width]
        result = model.predict([prediction_features])
        classification = result[0]
        print(classification)
        return JsonResponse({'result': classification, 'sepal_length': sepal_length,
                             'sepal_width': sepal_width, 'petal_length': petal_length, 'petal_width': petal_width},
                            safe=False)
```

and here is the template:

```
{%extends 'machinlearning/base.html'%}
{%block title%}Iris classification{%endblock %}
{%block content %}
<div class='container pt-5'>
<form action =""  method="POST"id ="input_form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div   class="form-group" >
    <label for="sepal_length" style="color:white">Sepal Length</label>
    <input type="number"  step="0.1" class="form-control" id="sepal_length"  placeholder="Sepal Length">
  </div>

  <div  class="form-group" >
    <label for="sepal_width">Sepal Width</label>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" id="sepal_width"  placeholder="sepal width">
  </div>

  <div   class="form-group" >
    <label for="petal_length">Petal Length</label>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" id="petal_length"  placeholder="petal_length">
  </div>

  <div   class="form-group" >
    <label for="petal_width">Petal Width</label>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" id="petal_width"  placeholder="petal width">
  </div>
  <button type="submit"  value = "Submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#modalex">classify</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalex" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Result</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="modal-body">
                <h5>Prediction Input:</h5>
                <div>Sepal Length: <span id="sl"></span></div>
                <div>Sepal Width: <span id="sw"></span></div>
                <div>Petal Length: <span id="pl"></span></div>
                <div>Petal width: <span id="pw"></span></div>
                <h5 class="pt-3">Prediction Classification:</h5>
                <div id="prediction"></div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"data-dismiss="modal">Try again</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on("#input_form",'submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'{%url "mlapps:iris"%}',
          data:{
              sepal_length:$('#sepal_length').val(),
              sepal_width:$('#sepal_width').val(),
              petal_length:$('#petal_length').val(),
              petal_width:$('#petal_width').val(),
              csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
              action: 'post'
          }, 
          success:function(json){
              document.forms["input_form"].reset();
              document.getElementByID("prediction").innerHTML=json['result']
              document.getElementByID("sl").innerHTML =json['sepal_length']
              document.getElementByID("sw").innerHTML=json['sepal_width']
              document.getElementByID("pl").innerHTML=json['petal_length']
              document.getElementByID("pw").innerHTML=json['petal_width']
             
              
              
          },
          error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {

            }
      });
  })
  
  </script>

{%endblock %}
```

Comment: `on("#input_form",'submit'`, Your event and selector need to be reversed, eg `on('submit',"#input_form",`

Comment: @Patrick Evans I 've reversed it but still nothing

Comment: Check your console for errors, as you also have `getElementByID` when it needs to be `getElementById` and will cause an error

Comment: Check your rendered code in browser code-view. check that url is correct in ajax and check the network tab of developer tools in the browser. and also check is there any error in the browser console.

Comment: it's solved I think it was a conflict in some script balis I ève delet them and it works I still looking on how tha effect the ajax cod